# Redshift Driver for JasperSoft Studio Community Edition

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have the following questions regarding JasperSoft Studio Community Edition.

1. How to add/install Driver for AWS Redshift in JasperSoft Studio Community Edition.
2. Is it possible to use Driver provided by AWS for Redshift in JasperSoft Studio Community Edition. (Add as external JAR and then use to connect to cluster).

Comment: It's a jdbc driver I can not see why not... add as library and provide connection parameter, if you manage consider to answer the question yourself.  http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/connecting-jasperreports-server-your-database

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully connected to my Redshift Cluster using **JasperSoft Studio Community Edition**. I have done the following method.

1. JDBC DRIVER : com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver.
2. JDBC URL : jdbc:redshift://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:5439/db_name.

   **NOTE : I HAVE USED THE URL WHICH IS USED IN SQL Workbench/J.**
3. USERNAME : XXXX
4. PASSWORD : XXXXX

**DRIVER SET UP : In the Driver Path Dialog Box provide the location of your Redshift Driver jar file.**

You can download the jar file from the following location :

https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar

After doing all the above steps I am able to connect to my Redshift Cluster.

Thanks.